# InvokeRequired in custom controls locking form UI

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a custom control. I am changing it's image opacity then loading other image.I am using `InvokeRequired` in my controls and it's working as expected. 
But when I add a control on a form, my form doesn't respond until my opacity changing is complete.
Although, I check `InvokeRequired`, why is my control locking the form?

My Project Complate Code [a link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=17599624223965769914)

**My Custom Controls Code**

```
void ChangeImageOpacity(int opacity,string image_path)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<int, string>(ChangeImageOpacity), new object[] { opacity, image_path });
        }
        else
        {
            this.Image = ImageOperation.ChangeImageOpacity(image_path, opacity);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }



 void ChangeImageOpacityStarter(PictureBoxMode mode)
    {
        if(mode==PictureBoxMode.OPENED)
        {                
            for (int i = 80; i >= 0; i-=5)
            {
                ChangeImageOpacity(i, string.Format(@"icons\{0}.png",0));
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 80; i += 5)
            {
                ChangeImageOpacity(i, string.Format(@"icons\{0}.png", this.ImageID));
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
        }
        else if(mode==PictureBoxMode.OPENED_TO_CLOSING)
        {
            for (int i = 100; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                ChangeImageOpacity(i, string.Format(@"icons\{0}.png", this.imageID));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                ChangeImageOpacity(i, string.Format(@"icons\{0}.png", 0));
            }
        }
        else if(mode==PictureBoxMode.DESTROY)
        {
            for (int i = 100; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                ChangeImageOpacity(i, string.Format(@"icons\{0}.png", this.imageID));
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Use this.BeginInvoke instead?

Comment: What does `ImageOperation.ChangeImageOpacity` do? Is that a time consuming process? Also why are you using `DoEvents` and `Sleep`?

Comment: it s changing picturebox current image to new image. i m increasing one image opacity during the current image changing. i m writing an image matchin games like this ([link](http://www.gamesforthebrain.com/turkish/mastercards/))

Comment: adding control on a for like this code

Comment: MyPictureBox box = sender as MyPictureBox;
 box.BoxMode = PictureBoxMode.OPENED;

Comment: a ve added my project code in my question

Answer (score 1):

Change Invoke to BeginInvoke so that it doesn't lock up your UI:

```
void ChangeImageOpacity(int opacity,string image_path)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action<int, string>(ChangeImageOpacity), new object[] { opacity, image_path });
    }
    else
    {
        this.Image = ImageOperation.ChangeImageOpacity(image_path, opacity);
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty obvious. You're taking up the UI thread while doing your opacity animation, and blocking it. One thread can only do one thing at the same time, so to do anything *but* the animation, you'd need to give up your work for a while to allow other UI operations to happen.

Your application also shows up as "Not responding", not re-rendering when invalidated, right? On older Windows, you couldn't even move the window. Again, the cause is the same - you're not pumping the message queue, so there's no way to process the windows messages like `WM_PAINT` or `WM_MOVE`.

The solution would be to make sure you're not blocking the UI while doing your animation. This is tricky, especially if you want it to appear smooth. You could use `await Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`, or a timer, or a `BackgroundWorker` or...

As an extremely hacky solution, you could just execute `Application.DoEvents` after every `Thread.Sleep` (or `ChangeImageOpacity`) you do - this is somewhat similar to using `await`, allowing the message queue to be pumped and executed. It also allows the code execution to interleave, though, which can be quite tricky to handle safely.

It seems you don't quite understand how `Invoke` or `InvokeRequired` works - somewhat obvious, since you're using `InvokeRequired` in the first place :) `Invoke` simply queues the operation you want to perform on the UI thread, and waits for it to finish executing. Whether you execute from a different thread (and thus `InvokeRequired` is `true` and you call `Invoke`) or not (and thus `InvokeRequired` is `false` and you call the method directly), the end result is executing code on the UI thread that sleeps for 1600ms, and does some extra CPU work to boot. Until it finishes executing, nothing else can happen with the form (apart from the hacks Windows now does to make stuff appear more responsive even if coded badly).

Comment: Yes you r right. it was rendering successfully but the form culdnt be move.

Comment: i was thinking when i use begininvoke in my custom control that was enough avoid the cross thread exception. so it could be izolated uı thread.

Comment: but it s creating in my form and added into tableadapter. so it depend on uı thread.am i right.

Comment: @IbrahimArac Yeah, you can't update the UI from anywhere but the UI thread - that includes stuff like having data bindings bound to a data table; if changing the data table results in an UI change, it *must* be done from the UI thread. It's one of the good reasons you really want a lot of decoupling between the UI and whatever else you're doing. I'm working with a project that does this kind of ad hoc mixing of UI and non-UI work, and it's a huge pain fixing all the (ignored) errors that arise from such willy-nilly multi-threading.